# How to programmatically create a virtual network share?

Tags: sftp, samba, fuse, file-sharing, cifs

I am extending an application, running on a linux server, which (very generally speaking) allows users to create versioned documents through a web interface. The "documents" live and get versioned in an SQL database. My task is to allow users to see documents of their selection as a network share. Is there a way to create a virtual samba share, an sftp server controlled by my application or something similar? If that's not possible/recommended, does it make sense to create a virtual fs with FUSE and share it (not sure how to programmatically share folders either)?

Comment: I think you would need to write a virtual file system driver that would be able to translate SQL contained data as file system content. The more usual "front end" to such a system is a web interface that allows you to browse and download the documents. They have additional advantages of being able to enforce review procedures.